# Examples which can be done by map reduce only and not aggregation framework in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I wanted to know about some examples or scenarios related to Mongo DB which can be done by map-reduce but not aggregation framework ?

Map-reduce is considered to be very powerful tool/mechanism of aggregating data. Then can some of you please share few scenarios where it is not possible for map-reduce to do it ?

Thanks & Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB currently aggregation framework is limited to 16MB of returned results.

MapReduce can write its output to a collection and has no size limitations.

MapReduce can group entire documents, aggregation framework works on field level.  MapReduce can map keys to values and values to keys which can't be done any other way.  MapReduce can also call/use various JavaScript built-in functions where aggregation is limited to functions and expressions which are built-in to its framework.